# Permission denied (publickey) when the server and local has correct keys

Tags: git, macos, ssl, ssh, pycharm

I am getting permission denied for ssh, I have the correct pub and private key saved in id_rsa.pub and id_rsa on the local machine, but still getting this error,
I have verified that the correct pub key is on the server I am authenticating with but this is only happening with my local machine,
For testing, I used the same pub and private key from another machine which was correctly authenticated.

Can anyone please help what's wrong with my local,
Also, I have given the correct permission to my keys and the email address  associated with the key

I did a verbose output for the ssh handshake and found one thing which I do not understand:

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method

Comment: Please verify the folder/file permissions of `~/.ssh` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. They should be accessible for you and **only** you, not for the group or others. SSH won't use a private key that has incorrect permissions set. Also, maybe your ssh is configured to look for the key elsewhere. Try connecting with `-i /path/to/id_rsa` to specify the key's location. If that works, then check/adjust your ssh's `IdentityFile` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Create a config file in ~/.ssh folder, then add below.

```
Host github.com
HostName github.com
AddKeysToAgent yes
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```